# DirectX 11 - AoS to SoA conversion using AVX causing corrupt vertex buffer at remapping

Tags: c++, directx-11, simd, avx

**Hi!**
 I'm implementing a particle system in DirectX 11 and use [Intel AVX instrinsics](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions) to update particle data as well as converting it from SoA (Structure of Array) to AoS (Array of Structures) before passing it to the IA-stage.

It seems like when I use AVX intrisincs in the remapping phase it causes the my vertex buffer, containing the particle vertices, to be corrupt and result in a crash!

I've structured my particle data in a SoA fashion:

```
float*      mXPosition;
float*      mYPosition;
float*      mZPosition;
```

---

I allocate alligned memory for each component

```
mXPosition = (float*) _aligned_malloc( NUM_PARTICLES * sizeof(float), 32 );
mYPosition = (float*) _aligned_malloc( NUM_PARTICLES * sizeof(float), 32 );
mZPosition = (float*) _aligned_malloc( NUM_PARTICLES * sizeof(float), 32 );
```

I create the vertex buffer using the `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` as well as `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE` to be able to modify particle data on the CPU.

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory( &desc, sizeof( desc ) );

desc.BindFlags              = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
desc.Usage                  = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.ByteWidth              = sizeof(ParticleVertex12) * NUM_PARTICLES;
desc.StructureByteStride    = sizeof(ParticleVertex12);
desc.CPUAccessFlags         = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

//Allocating aligned memory for array used for maping vertices to buffer
mVertices = (float*) _aligned_malloc( ( NUM_PARTICLES * 3 ) * sizeof(float), 32 );


if( FAILED( device->CreateBuffer( &desc, &subData, &mVertexBuffer ) ) )
    return E_FAIL;
```

---

Vertex buffer is successfully created.

**Remapping phase**

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
HRESULT hr = deviceContext->Map( mVertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource );

if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    size_t counter  = 0;
    for (int baseIndex = 0; baseIndex < NUM_PARTICLES / 8; baseIndex++)
    {
        //   Mapping from SOA-pattern to AOS-pattern 

        //Load
        __m256 xReg = _mm256_load_ps( &mXPosition[baseIndex * 8] );
        __m256 yReg = _mm256_load_ps( &mYPosition[baseIndex * 8] );
        __m256 zReg = _mm256_load_ps( &mZPosition[baseIndex * 8] );

        //Set test values
        xReg = _mm256_set_ps( 11.0f, 12.0f, 13.0f, 14.0f, 15.0f, 16.0f, 17.0f, 18.0f );
        yReg = _mm256_set_ps( 21.0f, 22.0f, 23.0f, 24.0f, 25.0f, 26.0f, 27.0f, 28.0f );
        zReg = _mm256_set_ps( 31.0f, 32.0f, 33.0f, 34.0f, 35.0f, 36.0f, 37.0f, 38.0f );

        //Shuffle
        __m256 xyReg = _mm256_shuffle_ps( xReg, yReg, _MM_SHUFFLE( 2,0,2,0 ) );
        __m256 yzReg = _mm256_shuffle_ps( yReg, zReg, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3,1,3,1 ) );
        __m256 zxReg = _mm256_shuffle_ps( zReg, xReg, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3,1,2,0 ) );

        __m256 reg03 = _mm256_shuffle_ps( xyReg, zxReg, _MM_SHUFFLE( 2, 0, 2, 0 ) );
        __m256 reg14 = _mm256_shuffle_ps( yzReg, xyReg, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3, 1, 2, 0 ) );
        __m256 reg25 = _mm256_shuffle_ps( zxReg, yzReg, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3, 1, 3, 1 ) );


        //Map, xyz
        __m128* vertexRegAOS = (__m128*)mTempPtr;

        vertexRegAOS[0] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg03 );  // x8,y8,z8,x7
        vertexRegAOS[1] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg14 );  // y7,z7,x6,y6
        vertexRegAOS[2] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg25 );  // z6,x5,y5,z5

        vertexRegAOS[3] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg03, 1 );    // x4,y4,z4,x3
        vertexRegAOS[4] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg14, 1 );    // y3,z3,x2,y2
        vertexRegAOS[5] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg25, 1 );    // z2,x1,y1,z1

        for ( int index = 0, subIndex = 0 ; index < 6; index++ )
        {
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
        }



    memcpy( mappedResource.pData, mVertices, sizeof( ParticleVertex12 ) * NUM_PARTICLES );
    deviceContext->Unmap( mVertexBuffer, 0 );
}
```

---

The application crashes when it hits this line

```
deviceContext->Unmap( mVertexBuffer, 0 );
```

and displays the message

```
D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11DeviceContext::Unmap: First parameter is corrupt or NULL. [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #13: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER1]
```

---

I may have located where the problem is but since I'm fairly new to using AVX I've not managed to solve it.

If I comment out this section:

```
        //Map, xyz
        __m128* vertexRegAOS = (__m128*)mTempPtr;

        vertexRegAOS[0] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg03 );  // x8,y8,z8,x7
        vertexRegAOS[1] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg14 );  // y7,z7,x6,y6
        vertexRegAOS[2] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg25 );  // z6,x5,y5,z5

        vertexRegAOS[3] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg03, 1 );    // x4,y4,z4,x3
        vertexRegAOS[4] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg14, 1 );    // y3,z3,x2,y2
        vertexRegAOS[5] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg25, 1 );    // z2,x1,y1,z1

        for ( int index = 0, subIndex = 0 ; index < 6; index++ )
        {
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
            mVertices[counter++] = vertexRegAOS[index].m128_f32[(subIndex++) % 4];
        }
```

Then it does NOT crash. The `mTempPtr` used at the type cast is defined like

```
mTempPtr = new float[6];
```

Any AVX experts out there who may have a clue on what I'm doing wrong?
I'm thankful for any suggestions!

Thank you!

Comment: Does it actually need to be remapped? Vertex buffers can be SoA as well IIRC and "not doing this" would be one way to make it not crash.

Comment: @harold I did not know that was possible! It would be super helpful if you could give me some pointers on how I perform that :)

Comment: Hm no, nevermind, can't deinterleave at that level. What line crashes btw?

Comment: @harold It crashes at the `deviceContext->Unmap( mVertexBuffer, 0 );`  I'm currently trying to change my implementation to just exclude the SoA to Aos conversion and just pass all the components in a fourth larger array

[ X1,X2,X3....XN, Y1,Y2,Y3....YN, Z1,Z2,Z3....ZN ] and reconstruct the input layout with offsets to each components. No idea if that is going to work but it's worth a shot!

Comment: Although it's probably not the cause of your issue you really shouldn't multiply by a float in your loop limit instead of doing an integer division.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your bug is allocating space for six 32bit floats, and then storing six 128bit vectors of floats.  You're prob. stepping on the bookkeeping data for the next allocation, leading to errors when you try to `free()`.

```
mTempPtr = new float[6];
__m128* vertexRegAOS = (__m128*)mTempPtr;
vertexRegAOS[0] = _mm_setzero_ps();
vertexRegAOS[1] = _mm_setzero_ps();  // buffer overrun here: you only had room for 2 more floats, but you store 4.
vertexRegAOS[2] = ...;  // step on more stuff
... // corrupt even more memory :P
```

You could save a uop or two by using a `VPERM2F128` and then a single 256b store, instead of 2x `VEXTRACTF128` (which apparently can't micro-fuse its store and store-data uops).

```
    vertexRegAOS[0] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg03 );  // x8,y8,z8,x7
    vertexRegAOS[1] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg14 );  // y7,z7,x6,y6
    vertexRegAOS[2] = _mm256_castps256_ps128( reg25 );  // z6,x5,y5,z5

    vertexRegAOS[3] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg03, 1 );    // x4,y4,z4,x3
    // vertexRegAOS[4] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg14, 1 );    // y3,z3,x2,y2
    // vertexRegAOS[5] = _mm256_extractf128_ps( reg25, 1 );    // z2,x1,y1,z1
    __m256 reg45 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps (reg14, reg25, 1|(3<<4) );
    _mm256_storeu_ps( (float*)(vertexRegAOS + 4), reg45);
```

Don't use 256b stores if your code has to perform decently on AMD Piledriver, though.  It has a bad performance bug that makes 256b stores WAY slower than two 128b.

Also, isn't the loop where you copy from `vertexRegAOS` to `mVertices[counter++]` just a `memcpy`?  I don't understand why you don't just store into it directly, with unaligned stores if needed.  It has no comments, and maybe I didn't spend enough time staring at it, if it doesn't actually copy every float in order.

Comment: You sir, just made my day! Good call pointing that bugger out. Everything works just fine now :)

Comment: Very interesting addition you made to your answer! I will take a closer look into that and do some benchmarking.

Comment: @SvinSimpe: Changing to 256b stores isn't going to make much difference (and will hurt on pre-Steamroller AMD), but avoiding the memcpy loop should make a big difference if your data set is even close to fitting in cache.  (Hopefully the compiler auto-vectorized your memcpy loop, but still.)